# Scala - Getting the error scala.xml.NodeSeq

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to write code to import XML file. I am missing some basic things -- Here is the code.

```
import xml._

case class Menu(name: List[String])
case class BreakFastMenu(food: List[Menu], price: List[Menu], des: List[Menu], cal: List[Menu])

def toMenu(node : Node): Menu = {
    val menuChart = (node \ "food")
    Menu(menuChart)
}

def toBreakFastMenu(node: Node): BreakFastMenu = {
    val name = (node \ "name").map(toMenu).toList
    val price = (node \ "price").map(toMenu).toList
    val des = (node \ "description").map(toMenu).toList
    val cal = (node \ "calories").map(toMenu).toList
    BreakFastMenu(name, price, des, cal)
}

val menuXML = XML.loadFile("simple.xml")
val food = (menuXML \ "food").map(toBreakFastMenu).toArray
food.foreach(println)
```

And the XML file is here - [simple.xml](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml)
Getting the error as

```
MenuXML.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.xml.NodeSeq
 required: List[String]
        Menu(menuChart)
             ^
one error found
```

Can anyone sort me out what the basics I am missing .

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the types. Menu takes List[String] and not scala.xml.NodeSeq.

You get the error, because you are passing the whole node (scala.xml.NodeSeq), not just the content of it.

I can recommend this blogpost to review for further explanation: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-extract-data-from-xml-nodes-in-scala

I would recommend to get your representation right first always. The best way to organize your case classes is to match the structure of the nodes. E.g. in case of a `<food>` node, you'd probably want to introduce a Food class.

```
  import xml._

  case class Food(food: String, price: String, des: String, cal: String)
  case class BreakFastMenu(foodItems: List[Food])

  def toFood(node : Node): Food = {        
    val name = (node \ "name").text
    val price = (node \ "price").text
    val des = (node \ "description").text
    val cal = (node \ "calories").text
    Food(name, price, des, cal)
  }


  val menuXML = XML.load("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml")
  val breakFastMenu = BreakFastMenu((menuXML \ "food").map(toFood).toList)
  breakFastMenu.foodItems.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Ok. But **Menu(menuChart.text)** this also gives the same error.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I rushed the answer, menuchart.text is String, and not List[String]. Ok, let me rewrite your solution, I'll edit my answer in a minute

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if this is what you are aiming for! It's important to get the representation right with the case classes otherwise it's hard to understand the code/reason about it.

Comment: Sorry For my previous comment.